# What is the difference between repositories and usecases?

Tags: android, repository-pattern, mvp, clean-architecture

I'm creating a chat application using clean architecture, I want to check if the user is logged in when the app starts, and open the login screen if he is not logged in, so my questions are:

1. What is the best way to implement that? Should I make the `LoginActivity` the launcher activity and check when the `LoginPresenter` starts if the user is already logged in then open the `MainActivity`? And where should I put the logic for checking if the user is authenticated (`IsLoggedInUseCase` maybe?)?
2. I don't really understand what is the difference between repositories and usecases, why should I make a `GetAllUsersUseCase` and `EditUserUseCase` .. etc, when there is already `UsersRepository.getAllUsers()` and `UsersRepository.editUser(User user)`? Why making a whole new class just to reference the the method that already exists in the repository?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Simply, `Use-Cases` handles your business logic, `Repositories` are the data layer which you store and access data.

For example when you open the Launcher activity (Let's call it `SplashActivity`)

First you start your `Presenter`:

```
mSplashPresenter.start();
```

Secondly, in your Presenter's start method you implement a logic if user is logged in or not? if is login navigate to dashboard, if not navigate to `LoginActivity`.

I assume you have a LoginUseCase.

```
public void start(){
      if(mLoginUseCase.isLoggedIn()){
          mView.navitageToDashboard();
      } else {
          mView.navigateToLogin();
      }
}
```

Third, you need a use case method like the following. (Again i assume you have a `UserRepository`)

```
public boolean isLoggedIn(){
     // This is your business logic.
     return mUserRepository.getCurrentUser() != null;
}
```

And in your `User Repository`:

```
public User getCurrentUser(){
    // This is your data 
    // You can access remote or local data with repository. 
    return mLocalDataSource.getUser();
}
```

**So why we need a Use-Case?** 
It's a simple business logic which decides if user logged in or not. This can be a more complicated business logic or you want to use this logic in other presenters. So with `Use-Cases`, you make your business code re-usable and avoid code duplicate in your presenters.

Later if you want to decide to change your login logic you only change your use-case, not all the presenters.

Let's decide a logic for your question: `EditUser`.

You have a Repository method `UsersRepository.editUser(User user)` which edit's the user.

You have a `Profile` screen which user can edit all fields. Also you have a `EditScreenDetail` screen that user can edit some of the fields which related by screen details can be seen by other people.

In both screen you **edit the user** but before call `UserRepository` method you need to check the required fields which is different by two screens. So you define a `ProfileEditUseCase` and `ScreenDetailsEditUseCase` to implement two different business logic. But the final operation is same. You edit the user by your repo. From remote or local.

**Summary:**

With `Use-Cases` you separate your business logic from presenters and data layer, avoid code duplicate in your presenters. Also you manage your business which can be used in other parts from one class.

I hope i explained it clearly.

Comment: Should `LoginUseCase` contain only one method, `isLoggedIn()` in that case? Why not having this logic in the repository, something like `UserRepository.isLoggedIn()` instead of creating a whole new class?

Comment: @MathewHany In most cases, If you combine multiple method in a method, It is a logic. Normally we should do all method combination in use-case methods. So we only touch use case, if we want to change logic later. Repository layer should be as dummy as possible. Repository is only responsible for fetch/save data. We don't ask to repository `isLoggedIn()`, we ask `getSession()`.